# Add two sheets together and shift specific column in new sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Im trying to add two sheets together in a specific way to see my data from my test bench. My plan is to build a Macro that dose this by it self.

[image]

[image]

[image: result]

Every picture is a different sheet so "Software - test 1 and 2" are separate sheets and the "Result" is its own sheet also. I have been trying for myself a while now and i can get the two sheets to copy over to the result sheet but i can´t get the "Software - test 1" and "Software - test 2" to shift next to each other (as shown in the "result sheet"). My script can only add the "test 2" under "test 1" but i need them to be beside each other. In a workbook i have +10 sheets.

```
Sub MergeSheets()
    Dim WorkSheetSource As Worksheet
    Dim WorkSheetDestination As Worksheet
    Dim RangeSource As Range
    Dim RangeDestination As Range
    Dim lngLastCol As Long
    Dim lngSourceLastRow As Long
    Dim lngDestinationLastRow As Long
    Dim SheetName As String
    Dim SkipSheets As String
    Dim Response As String ' Input form updateform
    Dim CopyFromColumne As Integer
    Dim CopyFromRow As Integer
    Dim AddMoreColumnes As Integer
    '----------- Open Form -----------------------------------
    Set StatusSheet = Nothing
    ShowUpdateForm
    If StatusSheet Is Nothing Then ' If error
        MsgBox "Wrong sheet selected"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Not Init Then ' If empty
        Exit Sub
    End If
    '-----------------------------------------------------------
    ' Get the name of the selected sheet
    Response = StatusSheet.Name
    'Set references up-front
    Set WorkSheetDestination = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Response)
    CopyFromRow = 1
    CopyFromColumne = 1
    AddMoreColumnes = 100 ' temporary
    lngDestinationLastRow = LastOccupiedRowNum(WorkSheetDestination) ' defined below
    lngLastCol = LastOccupiedColNum(WorkSheetDestination) ' defined below
    'Set the initial destination range
    Set RangeDestination = WorkSheetDestination.Cells(lngDestinationLastRow + 0, 1)
                                ' (lngDestinationLastRow + 2) = what row to start adding on, 1 = start from column
                                ' the 2 makes a blank row between sheeeeets
    'Loop through all sheets
    For Each WorkSheetSource In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ' Skip this sheets
        SkipSheets = ("Stacked Status,Cover sheet,Control,Column description,Charts description") & Response
        'Make sure we skip the "Import" destination sheet!
        If InStr(1, SkipSheets & ",", WorkSheetSource.Name & ",", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            ' Skip all Charts sheets and only chose Status sheets
            If InStr(WorkSheetSource.Name, "Status") Then
                MsgboxQuestion = "Add requierments from '" & WorkSheetSource.Name & "'  to '" & Response & "' (Yes/No)"
                'Display MessageBox
                Answer = MsgBox(MsgboxQuestion, vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Update Status sheet")
                If Answer = vbYes Then
                    ' Keep going through THIS!! function
                ElseIf Answer = vbNo Then
                    ' Jump out of for loop.
                    GoTo NextWorkSheetSource
                End If
                'Identify the last occupied row on this sheet
                lngSourceLastRow = LastOccupiedRowNum(WorkSheetSource)     
                        'Store the source data then copy it to the destination range
                    With WorkSheetSource
                        Set RangeSource = .Range(.Cells(CopyFromRow, CopyFromColumne), .Cells(lngSourceLastRow, AddMoreColumnes))
                        'Set RangeSource = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lngSourceLastRow, lngLastCol))
                                        '  (what start row, start column)
                        RangeSource.Copy Destination:=RangeDestination
                        CopyFromRow = 3 ' after the first sheet has been added set rowcopy to 3 to skip column name rows
                    End With             
                'Redefine the destination range now that new data has been added
                lngDestinationLastRow = LastOccupiedRowNum(WorkSheetDestination)
                Set RangeDestination = WorkSheetDestination.Cells(lngDestinationLastRow + 1, 1)
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Response).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 15 ' make a gray line 
            End If
        End If 
'If "for loop" answer is No, skip and take next one
NextWorkSheetSource:
    Next WorkSheetSource
    TurnOnFunctionality
    MsgBox "All selected Sheets are added together in 'Stacked Status'"
End Sub
```

The script works so that i use a form to select the "Result sheet" and then i loop through every sheet in the workbook. Every sheet with the keyword "Status" in the sheetname can be added to the "Result sheet". A dialog box will ask to add or not add the specific "Status sheet", if yes add, if no skip sheet. Then i loops through the workbook and asks for every sheet with the "Status" keyword in sheet name. If "yes" the sheet should be added as in picture 3 and the next "yes" should be added underneath but the "Software - test X" part should be added beside the "Software - test X" from the sheet before.
Is this possible to do or am i just dreaming that this could be done?
Thanks

Comment: To try the script you could just skip the Form part and add the sheet name directly to the Respons variabel :)